# My Python script seems to be executing an 'if' and 'else' statement simultaneous, resulting in an incorrect output. Any way to resolve this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently coding a script that is able to list the relative position(s) of a word inputted by a user in a sentence that has also been user-inputted.

For example, the user may input the sentence: "I love Stockoverflow and I love it with a passion".

If the user was to subsequently input the word 'love' when prompted, the system would automatically scan through the inputted sentence for the word 'love'. If in the inputted sentence, the position(s) to which the word composes the sentence are outputted, in this case: 'Love' appears in positions 2 and 5 in the sentence.

Despite this, the system outputs 'Word could not be found' AS WELL AS the relative positions of the word.

Any help? The system would appear to execute the 'if' and 'else' statement despite either one of the statements being inapplicable to the context of the inputted word.

My code is as follows:

```
sentence= input("Please enter a sentence: ")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence: ").lower()
words = sentence.lower()
words = sentence.split()
for (i, word) in enumerate(words):
    if (word == keyword): 
        print("Your key word,'",keyword,"'appears in positions '",(i+1), "of your inputted sentence.")
    else:
    print("Your entered word",keyword,"is not present in the sentence you entered.")
```

Its typical outputs:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Please enter a sentence:  Is Stockoverflow this.
Input a keyword from the sentence:  This
Your key word,' this 'appears in positions ' 3 'of your inputted sentence.
Your entered word this is not present in the sentence you entered.
=> None
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Indent your `else` statement to fix the error!

Comment: I'm surprised the empty `else:` clause (without a `pass`) didn't trigger a syntax error.

Comment: Sounds like you screwed up your indentation even further when you posted your code here, and your `else` was originally attached to the `for` instead of the `if`.

Comment: The same effect is produced despite amending the previously incorrect indentation of the 'else' statement.

Comment: "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence". Executing both the `if` and `else` clauses is exactly what you could expect to occur if your `else` clause were aligned with the `for` block, whereas it would require more code than is given in your question to reproduce absent such an error.

Comment: If you **really can** come up with a standalone reproducer that creates the bug even with fixed indentation, by all means post it (editing your post will put it in the queue for re-opening) -- but make sure that it really *is* a standalone reproducer, as the claim being made is extraordinary enough to put the onus on you to prove your case.

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance -- being a fully standalone reproducer ideally means you have no `input` or `raw_input` commands, and no dependency on variables not established, but rather hardcode constant values that will create the problem you're trying to show 100% of the time when copied-and-pasted from your question (and have trimmed any code not absolutely necessary to showcase that problem).

Comment: BTW -- editing a question or answer in a manner that makes its content inaccessible is considered vandalism.

Answer (score 1):

You missed some whitespace.

```
for (i, word) in enumerate(words):
    if (word == keyword): 
        print("Your key word,'",keyword,"'appears in positions '",(i+1), "of your inputted sentence.")
    else:
        print("Your entered word",keyword,"is not present in the sentence you entered.")
```

Comment: A comment would suffice

Comment: This just produces a *different* wrong result.

Comment: Even so, the same effect is produced.